# Traer Datos de Firebase y convertirlos en objetos de flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

me explico, estoy trasformado una aplicación estática a tener base de datos de firebase, bueno, el dilema es, como puedo transformar los datos que traigo en base de datos a objetos, para mantener la lógica que ya tiene. O sea, traer los datos, convertirlas en listas de objetos, por ejemplo, productos, tengo la lista en Firebase, pero a la hora de traerlos, no sé como puedo convertirlos en una lista de productos para despues mandarla directamente a a los widgets para ser mostrada.

Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida y de ante mano, gracias

Comment: Buenas, te recomiendo que pases por la sección de como preguntar y le des un buen vistazo. Esta pregunta no será bien recibida por la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

Es sencillo, supongamos que quieres traer datos de la base de un producto o varios, para crear el modelo(asi se le llama) simplemente debes crear un nuevo archivo donde crearas las variables y los métodos, te dejare un ejemplo sencillo, donde solo obtendremos el nombre y el precio para no hacer largo el ejercicio:

```
 class ProductModel{
  //variables que se usaran para recibir o enviar valores
  String? name;
  String? price;

  //constructor de la clase
  ProductModel({this.name, this.price,});

  //con este metodo podras enviar datos de ser necesario.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(){
    return {
      "name": name,
      "price": price,
    };
  }

  //con este metodo los valores que recibes los convieres en un objeto de tipo ProductModel.
  //es necesario que las claves tengan el mismo nombre que el json que recibes.
  factory ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return ProductModel(
      name: json["name"], 
      price: json["price"],
      );
  }
}
```

ahora, entiendo que tienes que tener una función para poder obtener el o los datos del producto, entonces sería algo así, para poder obtener los datos y transformarlos a uno o varios objetos:

```
    Future<List<ProductModel>?> getProducts(int idProduct) async{
  List<ProductModel>? listProducts;

  try {
    final request = await http.post(Uri.parse("www.apitest.com"),body: jsonEncode({"id": idProduct}));

    if(request.statusCode > 199 && request.statusCode < 300){
      final data = jsonDecode(request.body);

      if(data != null && data.isNotEmpty){
        listProducts = [];

        for (var product in data) {
          //Date cuenta que aqui es donde llamamos al metodo fromJson para poder convertir el json en un objeto ProductModel
          //Cada objeto que haya en la lista se convertira, aqui tu decides si deseas una lista o solo un objeto
          listProducts.add(ProductModel.fromJson(product));
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    rethrow;
  }

  return listProducts;
}
```

Eso es lo que debes hacer, aqui hay algo diferente ya que tu usas `firebase` y yo llamadas `http` pero el punto que debes entender de la funcion de obtener los datos es desde la validacion del `statusCode` eso es lo que debes entender y como llegaste al punto de hacer la conversion. Te dejo una pagina donde tu ingresas el json y te lo convierte automaticamente en un modelo de ese json, no es dificil de usar, solo debes escoger el lenguaje> [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io), espero y mi respuesta te haya despejado las dudas y si no que te sirva como guia.